# Sed replace last_updated: "1494099933" with last_updated: "1539339683412" (epoch time, through command substitution and double quotes)

Tags: sed

I am getting the epoch time through this command: `node -e 'console.log(Date.now())'`

Which (at the time of writing) gave me `1539339683412`.

There are a lot of yml files in which I want to change the datetime `1494099933` to `1539339683412`.

Currently my sed (on Mac OS X) command to do this for 1 file is:

`sed -i .bak "s/last_updated.*\".*\"/last_updated: $(node -e 'console.log(Date.now())')/g" ingress.yml`

This replaces it to:

`last_updated: 1539339683412`

The issue is that the double quotes are missing and for learning sed I want to replace it as:

`last_updated:"1539339683412"`

How do I do this?

I tried adding escaped quotes such as `\"`, for example: 
`sed -i .bak "s/last_updated.*\".*\"/last_updated: \"$(node -e 'console.log(Date.now())')/g\"" ingress.yml`

This gives the error: `sed: 1: "s/last_updated.*".*"/la ...": bad flag in substitute command: '"'`

I also tried: `sed -i .bak 's/last_updated.*\".*\"/last_updated: "$(node -e "console.log(Date.now())")"/g' ingress4.yml`.

Which resulted in: `last_updated: "$(node -e "console.log(Date.now())")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing quote goes before the final `/`.

```
sed -i .bak "s/last_updated.*\".*\"/last_updated: \"$(node -e 'console.log(Date.now())')\"/g" ingress.yml
```

Notice `...Date.now())'\"/g"` pro `...Date.now())'/\"g"`

The substitution string is the stuff between the last two slashes (or more generally separator characters; you don't have to use slash for that). Anything after the final separator is an option to the `s///` substution command (like `g` to substitute globally; which incidentally is superfluous here if you don't expect more than one match per line).

Comment: I wonder, how do you debug these things? Is it really just seeing the difference on one line or are there some tools that could help me distinguish it? I suppose being more experienced in sed would help, but I can imagine you can do some pretty complicated replacements with sed. Is it possible to comment regex code and use some good syntax highlighting and the like?

Comment: I can't believed I missed the `\"` and put it on the wrong spot. Thanks for pointing it out! That was really helpful.

Comment: Shell quoting is pretty straightforward once you figure it out. This isn't really a `sed` probler. (Some newer languages like Python and Perl make it easier to avoid many quoting conundrums.)

Comment: Oh and by the way `date +%s` is probably a lot more efficient than running `node` to get the current time.